# Lightning Component picklist not loading on dynamic row

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I add/remove rows dynamically in Lightning component. First row shows by default with plus button. Onclick plus button - adds row 2,3,4,etc., On first row Project picklist loads with values. But on 2nd, 3rd rows picklist value is not loading even though i call the same function which returns picklist value on the first row.

[image]

```
  <td>
     <div class="slds-select_container">
     <ui:inputSelect  aura:id="projectId"   class="slds-select"/>
     </div>
  </td>

 getemployeeProjects: function(component) {

   var parentId = component.get("v.userEmpRecdId");

    var action = component.get("c.getEmpProject");

    action.setParams({
        "empRecdId": parentId
    });
    var opts = [];
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        console.log('test === pick'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
         var allValues = response.getReturnValue();

        if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {
            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();

            if (allValues != undefined && allValues.length > 0) {
                opts.push({
                    class: "optionClass",
                    label: "--- None ---",
                    value: ""
                });
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
                opts.push({
                    class: "optionClass",
                    label: allValues[i],
                    value: allValues[i]
                });
            }
            console.log('test opts=='+opts);
            component.find('projectId').set("v.options", opts);

       }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

I get the below warning message in the console. Please help me fix the issue.
[image]

Comment: You may have to use a separate component for picklist. which is used as a child component in the iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is in line

```
component.find('projectId').set("v.options", opts);
```

When you have a single row then there is only one ui:input select with id as "projectId" so when you do **component.find('projectId')** it will return a object. on which you can set or get options value.

Now in 2nd case when you have multiple rows there are multiple ui:inputSelect components with aura:id as "projectid" so when you do **component.find('projectId')** it will return a array of objects.

Now if you want to append only one row at once you can just change `component.find('projectId').set("v.options", opts);`
with

```
var inputSelects = component.find('projectId');
if(inputSelects && !Array.isArray(inputSelects)){
   inputSelects.set('v.options',opts);
} else if (Array.isArray(inputSelects)) {
  inputSelects[inputSelects.length-1].set('v.options',opt)
}
```

Comment: thank you. This works for my scenario. Appreciated your help.

Comment: you can up vote my answer if it is correct :p

Comment: i couldn't do it... reason I need more reputation to vote it... sorry for that.. i had accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're only setting the options list on the first set of parameters. Instead, you should bind the options parameter and set it as an attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="projectOptionList" type="Object[]" default="[{ label: '-- Loading --', value: ''}]" />
```

...

```
 <ui:inputSelect  aura:id="projectId"   class="slds-select" options="{!v.projectOptionList}" />
```

...

```
component.set('v.projectOptionList', opts);
```

This will allow the list to work on all of the rows at once.

---

Demo code:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="List" default="[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[{label:'-- Default --'}]" />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
        <ui:inputSelect options="{!v.options}" label="Item" />
    </aura:iteration>
    <ui:button press="{!c.addOption}" label="Add Option" />
    <ui:button press="{!c.addItem}" label="Add Item" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    addOption: function(component, event, helper) {
        var opts = component.get("v.options");
        opts.push({label: 'Option '+(opts.length+1), value: 'opts.length' });
        component.set("v.options", opts);
    },
    addItem: function(component, event, helper) {
        var items = component.get("v.items");
        items.push({});
        component.set("v.items", items);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above idea didn't work.  When i select a value on first row the same value applied on all other rows. Requirements is i need to select different project in each rows. Project 1, Project 2 ,etc...

Comment: @user51204 Then you did something wrong. I literally wrote up an example that skips the server-side call, but can dynamically add rows and new options. Try it out and see.

Comment: @user51204 Based on your edited comment, check your "value" attribute. You've possibly bound the same value to each row item. This is different than what this answer addresses.