# Is it Possible to create Record with separate table (includes picklist)?

Tags: lightning

For Example i have an object named TEMS__C which can have records like Request1,request2 .

Request 1 record should hold some values like order number, status etc.. also below table value.

Note : Table should not be from another object

[image]

Comment: Only record types are applicable in scenarios where you want to have different set of picklist values

Comment: you can achieve by multiple ways but your questions need to more explanation,above functionality need in Lex or vf or lwc? i think below solution might be works for you if your looking in Lex https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263956/picklist-values-not-populating-for-dynamic-rows-in-lightning-component/263961?noredirect=1#comment399586_263961